# How to create a listview where we can swipe to select the item?

Tags: android, listview

I have created this list view to select the students who are attending a particular class by simply clicking on the items.
But i want to select the items by swiping the items from left to right. How could i do so?
[image: Attendance]

Here's the code inside **Attendance activity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
try {

                setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, new ArrayList()));
                ListView listView = getListView();
                listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

                new AddStringTask().execute();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
```

Comment: https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview  Are you looking for something similar?

Comment: Do you search for this in google, a lot are there,